# Calculating Coefficients for MA and AR representations of ARMA Models

Tags: statistics, time-series

Was working on a problem - how to find the coefficients for a MA and AR representation of given ARMA models. Specifications in the image. Thanks!

[Image of Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8WOD.png)

Comment: Can you show your work?

Comment: Sorry, I'm really unsure how to even get started with this problem. In over my head, but need to understand how to solve problems like these.

Comment: Do you know about backshift operator? Or causality and invertibility and the respective representations of the AR(p), MA(q) and ARMA(p,q)?